# How to erase the small gaps in tilemap in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap

I want to erase small gaps in my tilemap. The gaps look like this:

[image]

The texture I used has no gaps:

[image]

I tried by disabling anti aliasing.It didn't worked so what can I do in this case?

Comment: Are they really gaps or are they part of your texture? If you use a texture that is all single coloured, will the white lines still show up?

Comment: @TomTsagk I don't think there is any kind of gaps in my texture.

Comment: Is there any kind of bumpmap or normalmap linked to this texture?

Comment: Please post a larger image of the screenshot; at that size it's hard to tell much about the gaps. Also, do you get the gaps if you use a plain (all on color) texture?

Comment: I suggest you check the properties of the tilemap in the inspector. It seems that maybe there is a slight rotation or scaling applied and that could be why the result is not seamless. It’s a bit of a wild guess but the seams don’t look 100% straight to me.